# Copy cell values from one excel to another

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

I have 2 different excel workbook. What I would like to achieve is to transfer data over to another workbook; while matching the column and row name. So for example, when copying data of row 3 over from first workbook (as shown in first screenshot), uipath should help to make sure that it matches row name **B** and the column name **One**, **Two**, **Three**, **Four** and **Five** (as shown in 2nd screenshot).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply use sort in Excel before?

Comment: Hmmm true, but I am trying to automate this part here to fit into a larger automation process im trying to drive at.

Comment: Mhh I'm not sure I got you right. What do the screenshots mean? U have the 2. screenshot and want the first? Overall it's not that complicated. Just sort it. Should be easily possible with UiPath activities.

Comment: Will they always have the same column names and values is column A just in potentially different orders?